# how do you limit the visibility of FB likes to custom friend lists?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I require users to log in with Facebook, then want to allow them to select some friends (which i then use to create custom facebook friend lists).

Then i want to allow the user to "like" and "comment" on content in my app but limit (for privacy reasons) the visibility of the likes and comments only to the group they created.

I can't find a way to limit the visibility of likes and comments.  Anyone know if this is possible?  Do I need to abandon the social plug in to do it?

thanks,
Steve